# Viewpager receive notification when view in fragment is clicked

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager with some Fragments, In one Fragment (in that ViewPager) I have a button, I want to update some information at Activity (which contains that ViewPager) by click the button. Anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option is to use **interface**

Create the following **Communicator.java**

```
public interface Communicator {
    public void respond(int i);
}
```

**Implement** this **Communicator** in your **MainAcitvity**

And create a `instance` of this **Communicator** in your **fragment** like this

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    private Communicator com;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        com = (Communicator) getActivity();
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn:
            com.respond(1);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Whenever you **click** that **button** *it sends the int to the method which is residing inside the* **MainActivity**

which would look like following

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Communicator{

    @Override
        public void respond(int i) {
            int RECEIVED_VARIABLE = i;

        }}

    }
```

Here I'm receiving an int . You can use anything which you want

I hope this would help